# $3 \times n$ matrices with equal/consecutive row sums where the columns are permutations of $\{1,2,3\}.$

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

Let $S_n$ be the set or number (to avoid having to write the bars $||$ repeatedly) of $3 \times n$ matrices where each column is a permutation of $\{1,2,3\}$ and the row sums are equal. Let $T_n$ be like $S_n,$ only that the row sums are consecutive numbers. I wish to prove that $4S_n \le T_n$ for $n$ sufficiently large.

If we remove the last column of a matrix in $S_n,$ we get a matrix in $T_{n-1},$ and conversely there is exactly one way to append a column to a matrix in $T_n$ to get a matrix in $S_{n+1}.$ Thus, $S_n = T_{n-1}.$ If we append any matrix in $T_k$ to a matrix in $S_n,$ we get a matrix in $T_{n+k},$ so we have $T_{n+k} \ge T_k S_n = T_k T_{n-1}.$ These observations did not help much since $T_1 = 6, T_2 = 12, T_3 = 90,$ and we would need to find $k$ for which $T_k \ge 4^{k+1}$ to get something helpful.

Another approach I've tried involves constructing a set of $4$ column swap operations $a_1, \dots, a_4$ from $S_n$ to $T_n$ that are pairwise injective. In other words, $a_i(A) = a_j(B) \Rightarrow A=B.$ The most obvious operations are swapping either $1,2$ or $2,3$ in a column. Unfortunately, every time I try to use more than $2$ operations, pairwise injectivity fails. Does anyone have any hints for this problem? Any ideas for what $4$ operations would work?

Comment: Row sums for Tn consecutively increasing? Decreasing? Edit: I got it. They form a set of consecutive numbers.

Comment: Note that $S_2=6$ so the inequality fails here.  I think if you are going to evaluate $T_n$ from $n-1$ column matrices you need to also consider the ones that have rows that sum to $-2,+1,+1$ and $+2,0,-2$ relative to the average.  They can also give you $T_n$ matrices with one more column.

Comment: @RossMillikan Fails for which $k$? We have $\ge$ instead of $\le$ because only a subset of all possibilities for $T_{n+k}$ have been considered.

Comment: You have $S_2=6, T_2=12$, so $4S_2 \gt T_2$

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, that's why I asked about "sufficiently large $n$". I thought you were talking about the inequality $T_{n+k} \ge T_k S_n.$

Comment: For what is is worth, here is $S_n$ (and therefore $T_{n-1}$) in OEIS: https://oeis.org/A002898. This gives the nice  interpretation of $S_n$ as "Number of n-step closed paths on hexagonal lattice." This view may lead to a proof. Furthermore, they give the asymptotics $S_n\sim \sqrt{3}\cdot 6^n/(2\pi n)$. If you can prove that, you immediately get that $T_n\ge (6-\epsilon)S_n$ for all $\epsilon>0$, and $n$ large enough.